# C# WPF Material Design MaterialDesignFlatButton Hint\HighLight Color

Tags: c#, wpf, button, colors, material-design

How to change hint and animation color of buttons in my app.
What I tried:

```
        <!--PRIMARY-->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="#349fda" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="#333333" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#3d5671" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="#333333" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="#293a4c" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="#333333" />
        
        <!--ACCENT-->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentBrush" Color="#349fda" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentForegroundBrush" Color="#349fda" />
```

this change color of a button, BUT I need to change the animation and hint(when mouse hover on button) color from purple(default) to custom. How can I do it?

[My buttons now looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh9L9.png)

[I need hint like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMIFW.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `MaterialDesignFlatButton` brushes like this:

```xml
<Style x:Key="CustomMaterialDesignFlatButton" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrushColor">Red</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="Red" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Output:

[image]